# Nginx internal sending a 302

Tags: nginx

Using this documentation:

http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile

I added an internal location block

```
location /protected {
    internal;
    alias /protected/;
}
```

And then sent a file using the "X-Accel-Redirect" header (this is python/django code):

```
response = HttpResponse()
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = filename # /protected/foo.zip, no trailing slash
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=downloads.zip"
return response
```

But what results is that Nginx sends a 302 to /protected/foo.zip/ (notice the trailing slash) and this results in a 404.

What am I missing to make Nginx send the file to download instead of the 302?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was with SSL.

I forgot there were two configurations for the site, one with SSL and one without.

It seems that if Nginx gets this header and there is no matching internal block, it redirects you to the location that you specified.